# What version of rxjs is compatible with both Angular 16 and ngx-chips 3.0.0?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, angular16, ngx-chips, rxjs7

There are some issues of ngx-chips with angular 16. As of the current migration I am doing ngx-chips doesn't support rxjs 7.4 and with 6.5.3 it throws a build error Error: export 'filter' (imported as 'filter$1') was not found in 'rxjs'

The ngx-chips version I am using is 3.0.0

As per Angular guidelines

ANGULAR                 NODE.JS                             TYPESCRIPT          RXJS
**16.1.x || 16.2.x  ^16.14.0 || ^18.10.0                >=4.9.3 <5.2.0  ^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0**
16.0.x                  ^16.14.0 || ^18.10.0                >=4.9.3 <5.1.0  ^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0
15.1.x || 15.2.x    ^14.20.0 || ^16.13.0 || ^18.10.0    >=4.8.2 <5.0.0  ^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0
15.0.x                  ^14.20.0 || ^16.13.0 || ^18.10.0    ~4.8.2          ^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0
14.2.x || 14.3.x    ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0                >=4.6.2 <4.9.0  ^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0
14.0.x || 14.1.x    ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0                >=4.6.2 <4.8.0  ^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0

I am using node: 18.10.0, typescript: 4.9.3 and Angular: 16.2.3

I have already tried with multiple versions of rxjs and ngx-chips.

Answer (score 0):

It's an open source project, your best bet to know the truth on this is to look at the code itself. You can find it [here](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/blob/8e34983e49b0e595336a3c84a0e50946c98f1bdf/package.json#L47).

So the answer you're looking for is `7.4.0`. Not sure why you said

> ngx-chips doesn't support rxjs 7.4

But they clearly do.

Comment: As you can see https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/blob/8e34983e49b0e595336a3c84a0e50946c98f1bdf/package.json#L49 
The typescript version mentioned is 4.4.2 and angular 16.1.x or 16.2.x requires >= 4.9.3